# xCode not connecting application correctly on device, but correctly in simulator

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

Xcode is having difficulties connecting the app correctly on my device, but with the simulator, everything works perfectly. I noticed the issue after having corrected a typo in a text box and when  I run the app on my device (iPhone 4s) the typo is not fixed. Furthermore, I added a bit of localisation, and parts of the app are not localised. I even tried to run the app on an iPad, but to no avail. Same issues.

After this I tried to run it in the simulator... and BANG everything works perfectly. The typo is corrected, all the localised files are displaying as I wanted them to.

I am running the latest version of xCode (5.1.1) and Yosemite (public beta).

Is this an issue between xCode and Yosemite or is there another problem? (I only noticed this after I installed Yosemite.. is this a coincidence?)

Furthermore, if I were to install xCode beta (6), would this problem disappear?

Comment: "*Furthermore, if I were to install xCode beta (6), would this problem disappear?*" Is there an issue in trying it first and seeing if it works? Yosemite is beta software, you shouldn't rely on it to work for anything and everything until it is officially released.

Comment: Try cleaning the project and running it again.

Comment: @esqew thank you for your changes. I'm afraid I don't understand your question... 
I know Yosemite is beta software. I just wanted to see how it was working on this computer (and I ended up changing a few things in my app). As soon as I get home I will try to run the same program on my iphone with Mavericks.

Comment: @cabellicar123 I tried to clean it and run it.. but still no success. Nothing changes. Same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my computer, restarted my phone (after deleting the app from it) and now it works.. MAGIC!